# Get pusherapp members count in channel without counting self

Tags: javascript, pusher

Pusherapp counts yourself when you subscribe to get a members count. Is there any way to not include yourself?

I have a preview view with a members in channel count. If I join the room in another tab I would like that number to go up.

The problem with getting the count, then minus one is that when you actually do join the number won't go up. It also counts other members who are looking at the preview and not where I would actually intentionally subscribe them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 possible methods:

1. You can work out who **you** are in the `members` collection by comparing it to the `members.me` object. See: http://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_presence_channels#members_me
2. You can query Pusher's Web API to get a count of users. See:
   http://pusher.com/docs/rest_api#method-get-users

   Each user will have an ID so you can work out which one is the current user using that.
3. You could register a [Presence WebHook](http://pusher.com/docs/webhooks#presence) so that your server is notified whenever a user joins or leaves a channel. In this scenario you may need to maintain your own count, but you can get the initial value using method 2, above.

There is no way right now to simply query the members and say "exclude me" as part of that query. So the only solution is to get the full collection (on the client or server) and implement some custom counting logic.

Comment: Thanks I don't want to download the entire members collection though.

Comment: Yes the rest api is the current method I'm leaning towards, however it's not real time and requires polling. Since that counts toward the messages quota it probably needs some local caching which is a super pain.

Comment: Is it possible to set userId as part of the subscription? So I can set all the viewers to the same id and cause them to not count as part of the subscription but use their real id in a different subscription?

Comment: When you authenticate a user you supply a `user_id` this ensures that a user is only counted once as it is then identified as the same user. It also means you won't get duplicate `member_added` events if this user is already subscribed to the channel. I've also added a 3rd WebHooks method above that uses server functionality, but is realtime.